# How to reduce elasticsearch high load average/cpu usage?

Tags: elasticsearch, load, average, cpu-usage

My Elasticsearch cluster has been suffering from high load average recently, ranging between 2-5. I have a 5 node cluster and each node has 1 replica. The cluster total document size is 2G and 2,000,000 docs.

Here are some relevant information:

1. JVM

   ```
   $ ps -aux | grep java
   Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
   root      1232  380 37.6 11648332 3031468 ?    Sl   10:40 742:38 /usr/bin/java -Xms6g -Xmx6g -Xss256k -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=/usr/local/es1x/elasticsearch-1.3.2 -cp :/usr/local/es1x/elasticsearch-1.3.2/lib/elasticsearch-1.3.2.jar:/usr/local/es1x/elasticsearch-1.3.2/lib/*:/usr/local/es1x/elasticsearch-1.3.2/lib/sigar/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
   root      3016  0.0  0.0 103244   864 pts/1    S+   13:55   0:00 grep java
   ```
2. load average

   ```
   top - 15:34:14 up 9 days, 23:09,  1 user,  load average: 2.18, 2.30, 2.39
   Tasks: 169 total,   1 running, 168 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
   Cpu0  : 51.8%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 47.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
   Cpu1  : 46.3%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 53.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
   Cpu2  : 37.0%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 62.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
   Cpu3  : 35.6%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 63.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
   Cpu4  : 47.5%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 51.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
   Cpu5  : 33.3%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 66.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
   Cpu6  : 25.4%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 74.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
   Cpu7  : 12.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 87.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

     PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND 
   16637 root      20   0 9297m 3.6g  31m S 209.4 62.8   8964:38 java 
       1 root      20   0 19232 1012  840 S  0.0  0.0   0:38.37 init
   ```
3. bin/elasticsearch -v

   ```
   Version: 1.3.2, Build: dee175d/2014-08-13T14:29:30Z, JVM: 1.7.0_55
   ```
4. java -version

   ```
   java version "1.7.0_55"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
   ```
5. elasticsearch.yml

   ```
   cluster.name: XXXXXX
   node.name: 035

   index.cache.field.max_size: 500000
   index.cache.field.expire: 5m
   index:
     analysis:
       analyzer:
         index_ansj:
             alias: [ansj_index_analyzer]
             type: ansj_index
             user_path: ansj/user
             ambiguity: ansj/ambiguity.dic
             stop_path: ansj/stopLibrary.dic
             is_name: false 
             redis:
                 pool: 
                     maxactive: 20
                     maxidle: 10
                     maxwait: 100
                     testonborrow: true
                 ip: 192.168.0.159:6379
                 channel: ansj_term
         query_ansj:
             alias: [ansj_index_analyzer]
             type: ansj_query
             user_path: ansj/user
             ambiguity: ansj/ambiguity.dic
             stop_path: ansj/stopLibrary.dic
             is_name: false
             redis:
                 pool:
                 maxactive: 20
                 maxidle: 10
                 maxwait: 100
                 testonborrow: true
                 ip: 192.168.0.159:6379
                 channel: ansj_term
   index.analysis.analyzer.default.type: keyword
   ################################## Slow Log ##################################

   index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn: 10s
   index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.info: 5s
   # index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug: 2s
   # index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace: 500ms

   index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn: 1s
   index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.info: 800ms
   index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug: 500ms
   index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.trace: 200ms

   index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.warn: 10s
   index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.info: 5s
   index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.debug: 2s
   index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.trace: 500ms

   ################################## GC Logging ################################
   monitor.jvm.gc.young.warn: 1000ms
   monitor.jvm.gc.young.info: 700ms
   monitor.jvm.gc.young.debug: 400ms

   monitor.jvm.gc.old.warn: 10s
   monitor.jvm.gc.old.info: 5s
   monitor.jvm.gc.old.debug: 2s

   threadpool:
       index:
           type: fixed
           size: 30
           queue_size: -1
       search:
           type: fixed
           size: 30
           queue_size: 1000
   ```
6. curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_nodes/hot_threads'

   ```
   ::: [180][VNscyuhPS3u94QuyI2TfPQ][es180][inet[/192.168.0.180:9300]]

      96.9% (484.5ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[180][search][T#23]'
        2/10 snapshots sharing following 29 elements
          org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
          org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
          Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
   org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:252)
          org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.runAsDouble(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:273)
          org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.ScriptScoreFunction.score(ScriptScoreFunction.java:54)
          org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FunctionScoreQuery$CustomBoostFactorScorer.score(FunctionScoreQuery.java:175)
          org.apache.lucene.search.FilteredQuery$LeapFrogScorer.score(FilteredQuery.java:308)
          org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreCachingWrappingScorer.score(ScoreCachingWrappingScorer.java:49)
          org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator$RelevanceComparator.compareBottom(FieldComparator.java:774)
          org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldCollector$OutOfOrderMultiComparatorNonScoringCollector.collect(TopFieldCollector.java:484)
          org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.FilteredCollector.collect(FilteredCollector.java:61)
          org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:193)
          org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:163)
   org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:621)
          org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:175)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:581)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:533)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:510)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:345)
          org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:149)
          org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:261)
          org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:206)
          org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:203)
          org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:517)
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
          java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   4/10 snapshots sharing following 16 elements
          org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:163)
          org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:621)
          org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:175)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:581)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:533)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:510)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:345)
          org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:149)
          org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:261)
          org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:206)
          org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:203)
          org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:517)
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
          java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        4/10 snapshots sharing following 2 elements
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
          java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
      92.9% (464.4ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[180][search][T#18]'
        10/10 snapshots sharing following 10 elements
          sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
          java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
          java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.awaitMatch(LinkedTransferQueue.java:735)
          java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.xfer(LinkedTransferQueue.java:644)
          java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue.take(LinkedTransferQueue.java:1137)
          org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.SizeBlockingQueue.take(SizeBlockingQueue.java:162)
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
          java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
      67.6% (337.9ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[180][search][T#8]'
        7/10 snapshots sharing following 28 elements
          org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
          org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
          Script9.run(Script9.groovy:1)
   org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:252)
          org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$GroovyScript.runAsDouble(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:273)
          org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.ScriptScoreFunction.score(ScriptScoreFunction.java:54)
          org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FunctionScoreQuery$CustomBoostFactorScorer.score(FunctionScoreQuery.java:175)
          org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreCachingWrappingScorer.score(ScoreCachingWrappingScorer.java:49)
          org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator$RelevanceComparator.compareBottom(FieldComparator.java:774)
          org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldCollector$OutOfOrderMultiComparatorNonScoringCollector.collect(TopFieldCollector.java:484)
          org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.FilteredCollector.collect(FilteredCollector.java:61)
          org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:193)
          org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:163)
          org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:621)
          org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:175)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:581)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:533)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:510)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:345)
          org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:149)
          org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:261)
   org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:688)
          org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:677)
          org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:275)
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
          java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   3/10 snapshots sharing following 16 elements
          org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:163)
          org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:621)
          org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:175)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:581)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:533)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:510)
          org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:345)
          org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:149)
          org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:261)
          org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:688)
          org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:677)
          org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:275)
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
          java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   ```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: The question is how that is to reduce the load average?

Comment: It looks that the serve runs well, average load is not problem. Please explain, why you try to reduce the load. But here two hints: 1. Upgrade to latest Java an GC, 2. reduce amount of indexed field, 3. reduce the amount of indexed (new) documents per time.